# Architecture of apps that dont use persistant store - Application subclass holding data - getting it inside fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, architecture

I am working on an application that loads json from server containing all the bundled data needed for the application.

I load the json in `MainActivity.onCreate()` and figured I should store it in the MyApplication subclass. (should I?)

My UI (for now) is Activity containing 4 fragments via ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter.

What I would like to have if fragments that dont really know about world around them and data gets only passed into them inside constructors

But the trouble is orientation changes, when I setup logs, it seems that fragment's onCreate gets called before activity's...

So my question is, should every fragment then manage its own data (parceling on orientation changes in onSaveInstanceState) or should just request it from application on every onCreate. i.e, should the data get passed inside via constructor and than managing orientation changes with savedInstances inside (application giving fragment its data) OR fragment requests (`myApp.getData()`) it from application subclass holding the data.

What is the correct pattern for this kind of applications that just hold data in memory and dont persist anything

---

My question is about direction of communication with fragments. Should be treat fragments as "dumb" object and only pass data to them from outside OR should we allow "upstream" (singleton) call to get data from Application subclass

Comment: You can do it like: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html / http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments - let such a fragment handle all the things, it could fetch the data asynchronously once created and retain it.

Comment: is worker fragment really meant for storing the data or just surviving orientation changes?

Comment: It will survive as long as you don't change the activity. Can be used to retain data / do background processing / .. whatever you like. If you want to keep data available for multiple activites you may have to store it either in a singleton or the `Application` (which is a singleton as well). Depends on your requirements.

Comment: Yes, youre right, but that not really my question. My question is about direction of communication with fragments. Should be treat fragments as "dumb" object and only pass data to them from outside OR should we allow "upstream" (singleton) call to get data from Application subclass